# Page 2 of my blog doesn't load. Page 1 is reloaded insted

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have a strange issue with a Wordpress website. Somehow the second page of the blog isn't loaded with a custom permalink setting. With the default setting it al works fine.

For example; the pagination shows the follow link http://www.magicwithin.coach/slide/blog/page/2/ but http://www.magicwithin.coach/slide/blog is loaded when the link is clicked. If I go to the first link directly the second link loads aswell.

I can't seem to figure out what's going wrong. Can someone help me?

To be sure, this is the pagination I use:

```
<?php 
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;

    $argus = array( 'post_per_page' => '5', 'paged' => $paged );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $argus );
    if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ): while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
```

Pagination:

```
<?php global $wp_query; $big = 999999998;

                            echo paginate_links( array(
                                'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                                'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                                'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                                'prev_text' => '<<',
                                'next_text' => '>>',
                                'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
                                ) );
                        ?>
```

Update:

I resolved it. I had multiple loops on the page and I think the pagination got a bit confused about which one to use I guess. I've put the loop on a seperate template and everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than build your own `WP_Query` to list blog posts, I recommend letting WordPress handle the query for you.

To do this, rename your blog template to `index.php` and use the default query:

```
<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()): the_post() ?>
  // Display your post
<?php endwhile; endif ?>
```

If the page is still not being honored, try visiting your site's `/wp-admin/options-permalink.php` and clicking the "Save Changes" button to ensure your permalink rewrites are saved.

Note: If your blog is not your front page, you can tell WordPress which template is your front page by naming it `front-page.php`.

Comment: I have multiple loops in that template that's why it has a custom query. The strange thing is if I delete everything but this query nothing happens but in a seperate template it works fine.

I don't really understand why but it's resolved either way.

Comment: @Ermen What do you see if you add `var_dump($paged);` before your `new WP_Query()` line? Is the `$paged` variable what you're expecting?